# Cannot add another one account to outlook 2010

Tags: exchange-2010, outlook-2010

I have two aacounts added in outlook 2010, but when I try add another one account I recive error something like that:

```
 impossible to find a match for the name. This name does not match any name in the address list.
```

All added accounts are in one domain, but the mail server is Microsoft Exchange 2010. I checked the event viewer but there is no error with Outlook. Also I try manual configuration in outlook but effect is the same, outlook cannot create account. I thought it might be a firewall issue, I turned off but it also did not help. the same account I tried to add using a different mail client **"thunderbird"** and for this mail client everything is working properly

Please give me some advice.

Regards
Mick

Comment: Is the mailbox for this account visible in the Address Book?

Comment: Yes is visible. In this PC I tried login to mailbox with using OWA and I logged out correctly. Maybe I must re-install all Outlook, What do you think?